A question about a module has a filtration with graded factors
When I read a paper, the author introduces a concept in a proof of a lemma. But he doesn't explain it.
I will briefly describe the following.

Let $M$ be a $R$-module, the author says $M$ has a filtration with the
associated graded factors $N_k$.

I'm not familiar with filtration.
Does it mean there exists a sequence $0\subset M_1\subset M_2\subset \cdots\subset M_n=M$ and for all $1\le i\le n-1$, $M_{i+1}/M_i$ is isomorphic to graded factors $N_k$?
This is my guess based on composition series.
I want to know if it is true.
Any help and references are greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Your guess is right but note that the filtration certainly does not need to be finite in general. Take a silly example here and consider $M=k[x]$ as a module over itself with filtration $F_iM$ by degree. This is not finite but you get $\bigcup_{i}F_iM=M$. Also note that there is also the concept of a decreasing filtration. Without seeing the paper you're reading it is impossible to tell what the author means but in either case the construction works the same.

@LT1918  Thank you.
